# interrupt watson studio AI experiment

Tags: watson-studio

In watson studio the AI experiment is running from past 11 days. If I press stop the process from running it is giving an error code 500. How to stop this AI experiment ?

code generated by watson AI

Comment: The request to stop 'Recommender' failed.
Unexpected response code: 500

Answer (score 0):

Product manager for this offering here.  Thanks for opening this question as this is something we are working to fix ASAP.  When you see a 500 error for an AutoAI experiment, it has already been stopped; but as you can see there is a UI issue updating this.

To get support on this, please go to the main navigation in the top left of the Watson Studio interface and scroll down to `Manage Tickets` and open a support ticket describing the situation.  This allow us to work closely with you to troubleshoot this issue.

Hope this helps,
Greg

Comment: Dear Greg,
This screen shot gives you a better perspective I guess
<img src="https://pasteboard.co/IpyB3GQ.png" width="100" height="100">
It is still running pl. stop this process

Answer (score 0):

I believe the current version already fixed this problem. @Raavibn, can you confirm? Thanks!